# how to prevent any page getting loaded if person not logged in struts2

Tags: java, jsp, session, struts2, struts

I have been googling from week now. Still have not got any solution which resolves my problem. My strtus2 web application is simple. There is a login page once the login is successful then it has to redirect to the success page. But my problem is if i right click on the `success.jsp` and run that page, still that page is loading without any session but my requirement is `success.jsp` should never get loaded rather it should redirect to the `login.jsp` page.

**login.jsp:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%> 
<s:form action="login"> 
<s:textfield name="username" label="User Name"/> 
<s:password name="password" label="Password"/> 
<s:submit value="Login"/> 
</body>
</html>
```

my pojo class for Login.

```
package com.cm.ccb.login;

public class Login {
private int userid;
private String username;
private double password;
private String email;
private double phone;
public int getUserid() {
return userid;
}
public void setUserid(int userid) {
this.userid = userid;
}
public String getUsername() {
return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
this.username = username;
}
public double getPassword() {
return password;
}
public void setPassword(double password) {
this.password = password;
}
public String getEmail() {
return email;
}
public void setEmail(String email) {
this.email = email;
}
public double getPhone() {
return phone;}
public void setPhone(double phone) {
this.phone = phone;
}
}
```

My loginAction class.

```
package com.cm.ccb.login;

import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.SessionAware;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport  implements SessionAware { 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 
private String username; 
private String password;
Map<String, Object> session;

SessionMap<String,String> sessionmap;  
LoginDao dao=new LoginDao(); 
@Override
public void validate(){ 
if(username.length()==(0)) 
this.addFieldError("username", "Name is required"); 
if(password.length()==(0)) 
this.addFieldError("password", "Password is required"); 
} 
@Override
public String execute(){

if(dao.find(getUsername(),getPassword())) {
return "success";

}
else

return "error"; 
} 

public String getUsername() {
return username;
}
public void setUsername(String username) {
this.username = username;
}
public String getPassword() { 
return password; 
} 
public void setPassword(String password) { 
this.password = password; 
}
public void setSession(Map<String, Object> session) {
this.session = session;
```

}

}

My loginDao class

```
package com.cm.ccb.login;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;

import com.cm.ccb.mapping.HibernateUtil;

public class LoginDao { 

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
public boolean find(String username, String password) { 
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession(); 

String SQL_QUERY = " from Login l where l.username='"+username+"' and l.password='"+password+"'"; 
System.out.println(SQL_QUERY); 
Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY); 
Iterator<Login> it = query.iterate(); 
List<Login> list = query.list(); 
if (list.size() > 0) {


return true; 
} 

return false; 
}
}
```

my success.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%> 
success

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `cookies`..your problem can be solved by it

Comment: Page is loading? Did you restrict it by a security constraint?

Comment: That code is illegible because it's unformatted. What do you mean, "right click on success.jsp and run it?" You need to test your application by running it inside a container like Tomcat etc. There's nothing in "success.jsp" that disallows access without a session. You should not be accessing JSP pages directly *anyway*, rather running them through an S2 action, even if it's an empty one. It sounds more like you need a login interceptor.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to achieve this, but I am explaining one way to store session value.

**Step 1** In your **Login Action** when users login put username in **session** if username and password are correct.

```
 Map<String,Object> session = ActionContext.getContext().getSession();

 session.put("username", username);
```

**Step 2** Implement Interceptor Which checks this session value. Create package `Interceptors` and create a class `AuthorizationInterceptor.java` in it.

```
package Interceptors;

import org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.SessionMap;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.Interceptor;

public class AuthorizationInterceptor implements Interceptor {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1841289944579731267L;

@Override
public void destroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public String intercept(ActionInvocation inv) throws Exception {
    ActionContext context = inv.getInvocationContext();

    //for login and register actions ignore checking
    if(context.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("login") || context.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("register"))
    {
        return inv.invoke();
    }
    SessionMap<String,Object> map = (SessionMap<String,Object>) inv.getInvocationContext().getSession();
    if(map==null)
    {
        return "login"; 
    }
    Object user = map.get("username");      
    if(user==null ||user.equals("") || map.isEmpty() || map == null ){                  
        return "login";     
    }

    return inv.invoke();
}

}
```

**Step 3:** Configure this interceptor in `struts.xml`

```
<package name="mydefault" namespace="/" extends="struts-default">

    <interceptors>
        <interceptor name="Authorizeuser" class="Interceptors.AuthorizationInterceptor"></interceptor>

        <interceptor-stack name="myStack">
            <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            <interceptor-ref name="Authorizeuser" />
        </interceptor-stack>
    </interceptors>

    <default-interceptor-ref name="myStack" />
    <global-results>
          <result name="login">login.jsp</result>
     </global-results>

    ...your Actions here....
</package>
```

Up to this it will prevent action urls if user is not logged in

**Step 4** Prevent jsps -> Put following code in the jsp you want to prevent e.g. success.jsp

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%> 
 < %
    HttpSession sess = request.getSession(true);
    if (sess.getAttribute("username")==null)
    {
    % >
        <jsp:forward page="/login.jsp?msg=You will have to login first in order to access other pages"></jsp:forward>
    < %
    }
% >
<html>
    <body>
        success
    </body>
</html>
```

**Note:** Instead of using session, you can also use cookies,context variables etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can solve your problem by using cookies..On your login page at the time of login, add a new cookie. Now on your `success.jsp` page check that cookie for null value..if it is, redirect again to `login.jsp`

Let's say you added a cookie named userid on your login page as

```
 Cookie ck=new Cookie("usrid",userid);
 response.addCookie(ck);
```

Now on your `success.jsp` page you can check it for null value as :

```
 String userid = "";
 try 
 {
      Cookie[] ck = request.getCookies();
      for (int i = 0; i < ck.length; i++) 
      {
          if (ck[i].getName().equals("usrid")) 
          {
              userid = ck[i].getValue();
              break;
          }
      }
 } 
 catch (Exception ex) 
 {
     if (userid.equalsIgnoreCase("")) //if your cookie is null it will be redirected to login.jsp
     {
          response.sendRedirect("login.jsp");
     }
 }
```

This way, whenever you try to open `success.jsp`,it will be redirected to `login.jsp` if you have not logged in

Comment: You have added response.addCookie(ck); but in this line I am getting response cannot be resolved. why? :(

Comment: you have to write this statement in your jsp page within the scriplet tag

Comment: It seems you are not using any security framework like spring security which makes very easy to handle such use cases. Alternatively you should write your own Authentication Interceptor which checks for every request if user is already logged in or not and then redirect him to appropriate page. Using Interceptors is the   stadard way for Struts2 if you dont use any security framework like Spring Security